# Why do cookies (that show in the Postman app) not show in the Python response variable?

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, postman

https://open.spotify.com/search/results/cheval is the link that triggers various intermediary requests, one being the attempted request below.

When running the following request in Postman (Chrome plugin), response cookies (13) are shown but do not seem to exist when running this request in Python (`response.cookies` is empty). I have also tried using a session, but with the same result.

**update:** Although these cookies were retrieved after using Selenium (to login/solve captcha and transfer the login cookies to the session to use for the following request, it's still unknown what variable/s are required for the target cookies to be returned with that request).

How can those response cookies be retrieved (if at all) with Python?

```
url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search"

querystring = {"type":"album,artist,playlist,track","q":"cheval*","decorate_restrictions":"true","best_match":"true","limit":"50","anonymous":"false","market":"from_token"}

headers = {
    'access-control-request-method': "GET",
    'origin': "https://open.spotify.com",
    'x-devtools-emulate-network-conditions-client-id': "0959BC056CD6303CAEC3E2E5D7796B72",
    'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36",
    'access-control-request-headers': "authorization",
    'accept': "*/*",
    'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate, br",
    'accept-language': "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "253b0e50-7ef1-759a-f7f4-b09ede65e462"
    }

response = requests.request("OPTIONS", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```